# Calling C# method from javascript in MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, methods

i'm trying to call a c# method from javascript but nothing works. What this have to do is that i call the javascript after user press enter, then i call the method in c#, the API try to find the city, then i show the temperature of the city that he typed. But i tried a lot of thing, but nothing worked.

the code:

My JavaScript:

```
function enterpressalert(e, textarea) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            var tb = $('#search-bar').val();

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("getWeather", "IndexController")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                // we set cache: false because GET requests are often cached by browsers
                // IE is particularly aggressive in that respect
                cache: false,
                data: { city: tb },
                success: function () {
                    $('#search-bar').val() = 'funcionou';
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

My c# method that i'm trying to call:

```
[WebMethod]
public LocalWeather getWeather(string city)
{
    LocalWeatherInput input = new LocalWeatherInput();

    input.query = city;
    input.num_of_days = "5";
    input.format = "JSON";

    FreeAPI api = new FreeAPI();
    LocalWeather localWeather = api.GetLocalWeather(input);

    return localWeather;
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What is the error? Where is it going wrong?

Comment: nothing happens, it does not show any error message.

Comment: OK. Does the AJAX method get called?

Comment: Instead of passing "IndexController", try passing just "Index"

Comment: @Vinicius Yes. Is your AJAX call happening?

Comment: @rhughes no, its not, i put error, and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Place a break point in getWeather() function and try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public LocalWeather getWeather(string city)
{
    LocalWeatherInput input = new LocalWeatherInput();

    input.query = city;
    input.num_of_days = "5";
    input.format = "JSON";

    FreeAPI api = new FreeAPI();
    LocalWeather localWeather = api.GetLocalWeather(input);

    return localWeather;
}
```

and also check whether your are using url routing in global.asax